# How to use fetch to POST form data as JSON for GraphQL API?

Tags: node.js, post, graphql, fetch, form-data

I want that when entering data from the registration form after clicking on the "Register" button, the data is sent to GraphQL and then entered into mongoDB.
GraphQL queries in the playground works, but I want the data in the database to appear after I enter the data in the registration and authorization form.

After clicking on the register button, writes "POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?"

I'm using Node.js, GraphQL and mongoDB.

Submit.js:

```
const regForm = document.getElementById("reg-form");

regForm.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit);

async function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const form = event.currentTarget;

    const url = form.action;

    try {
        const formData = new FormData (form);

        const responseData = await postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData });

        console.log({ responseData });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

async function postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData }) {
    const plainFormData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
    const formDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(plainFormData);

    const fetchOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },

        body: formDataJsonString,
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);

    if (!response.ok) {
        const errorMessage = await response.text();
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
    }
    return response.json();
}

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("http://localhost:4000/graphql", (request, response) => {

    const newUser = {
        firstName: request.body.firstName,
        telephone: request.body.telephone,
        email: request.body.email,
        password: request.body.password
    };
    response.status(201).json(newUser);
});
```

index.js (server):

```
const { ApolloServer, gql, PubSub} = require('apollo-server');
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');
const typeDefs = require('./typeDefs.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);

const pubSub = new PubSub();

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ req }) => ({ req, pubSub })
});

mongoose
.connect('..., 
{useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => {
    console.log('mongoDB is connected');
    return server.listen();
})
.then(res => {
    console.log(`Server is running at ${res.url}`);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

typeDefs.js:

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

module.exports = gql`
    type Article {
        id: ID!
        title: String
        subtitle: String
        description: String
        date: String
        firstName: User!
    }
    type User {
        id: ID!
        firstName: String!
        token: String!
        email: String!
        telephone: String!
    }
    type Query {
        getArticles: [Article]
        getArticle(id: ID!): Article
    }
    input InputRegister {
        firstName: String!
        telephone: String!
        email: String!
        password: String!  
    }
    type Mutation {
        register(inputData: InputRegister): User!   
        login(email: String!, password: String!): User
        addArticle(title: String!, subtitle: String!, description: String!, firstName: String!, date: String) : Article!
        deleteArticle(id: ID!): Article!
    }
    type Subscription {
        newArticle: Article!
    }
`;
```

user.js (Model):

```
const { model, Schema} = require('mongoose');

const newUser = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    telephone: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
})

module.exports = model('User', newUser)
```

Comment: you don't need any of FormData-related parts ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#example-4 ... just call `resp()` in on submit handler fn (now is "called" at start, "called" because no resp`()` - should be some `data = await resp(); setData( data.json() )` ... values can be read from form or use separate input values stored using `useState` (follow 'normal' form react tutorials)

Comment: @xadm I don't use React

Comment: it doesn't really matters ... 3/4 of code is useless (input values can be read from form using `event target`) ... you're calling some `postFormDataAsJson` (unknown?) instead of all the rest with `const res = await resp(); console.log(res);`, destructure/extract later

Comment: @xadm I can't start the server now after installing apollo-server-express)

TypeError: server.listen is not a function when ```return server.listen();```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error states you've got nothing to parse bodies, and I didn't see any framework being used in your code. Normally, you'd have a framework do it via some parsing library. Still,  if you want it done without it. Nicely explained here, look up: [how to parse without a framework](https://itnext.io/how-to-handle-the-post-request-body-in-node-js-without-using-a-framework-cd2038b93190)

My advice though: install express and use body-parser

Edit:

The code in the article doesn't use graphql, hence why they're setting up the `'/user'` endpoint with `app.post(...)`. Graphql is meant to work on a *single* route. Usually .../graphql. Now that you have installed express and apollo just configure them.

I modified some of your code:

Note:

- you'll have to uninstall apollo-server and install apollo-server-express
- might even work without explicitly applying bodyParser to express as it is deprecated, but doesn't hurt having it in for now

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { ApolloServer, gql, PubSub } = require('apollo-server-express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const resolvers = require('./resolvers');
const typeDefs = require('./typeDefs.js');

const pubSub = new PubSub();

const app = express();
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true,
    })
  );
app.use(bodyParser.json());
  
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ req }) => ({ req, pubSub })
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app });
mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);

mongoose
.connect('..., 
{useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => {
    console.log('mongoDB is connected');
    return server.listen();
})
.then(res => {
    console.log(`Server is running at ${res.url}`);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: According to your advice, I installed express using the information from the given site:[How to use fetch to POST form data as JSON to your API] (https://simonplend.com/how-to-use-fetch-to-post-form-data-as-json-to-your-api/)  I can't understand what, in my case, to register in ```app.post(?)```

Comment: @mindfield_tester I'm uninstall apollo-server and install express apollo-server-express, but after npm start writes:
TypeError: server.listen is not a function
when return server.listen();

Comment: @mindfield_tester Why did it work before apollo-server-express, but not now?

Comment: Hmm, server.listen not a function... Try app.listen(...) and see if that works

Comment: @mindfield_tester Server is running at undefined)

Comment: Yup, server doesn't even have that method and that is fine. But the app variable has and  app.listen() should spin the server up. Did that work?

Comment: @mindfield_tester Server works, but after sending and clicking on the register button writes ```Cannot POST /```

Comment: @mindfield_tester I update submit.js, check please.

Comment: I think you're trying to post to an endpoint that isn't configured. Assuming you haven't changed the rest of the code, you need to send requests to a graphql endpoint. In your case it'd be smth like `http://localhost:PORT/graphql` and not `'./index'`.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to set this up correctly? I just think it might be better to show you on Skype, but my English leaves much to be desired)?
In an emergency, change graphQL to REST API @minefield_tester

Comment: I wrote the graphql address ```http://localhost:4000/graphql``` to the endpoint, but after sending it writes ```Must provide query string.``` How to fix this you need to register a request from ```mutation Register``` in the post method?

Comment: I apologize for getting it out, I just really can't figure out how to do it, I'm already glad that there is another mistake.The server somehow barely managed to configure and implement sending to graphql via ```fetch()``` to ```POST``` I can't (