# How do set up a GraphQL endpoint?

Tags: express, post, graphql, apollo-server, body-parser

The whole project is in the next post: [How to use fetch to POST form data as JSON for GraphQL API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858961/how-to-use-fetch-to-post-form-data-as-json-for-graphql-api), I can't figure out how to implement an `GraphQL` endpoint, so that after clicking on the register button, the data is sent to `GraphQL` and then to `mongoDB` to create a new user, although everything works fine in the `GraphQL` Playground.

Comment: if works in playground (check network request) then work on FE/js until network request will have the same shape

Comment: @xadm In the registration ```form```, I indicated ```action = "http: // localhost: 4000 / graphql" id = "reg-form" method = "post"```.
In submit.js accessed ```id```, but can't figure out what's the matter?

Comment: There is documentation or a video on how to set it up, mostly using ```React```, but I don't use ```React```, that is, I have a FE, I want to implement a backend, I apologize for the obviousness, I'm just a noob and this is new to me.

Comment: @xadm Can you please tell me in which sources I can find information related to my question?

Comment: forget about formdata/action/etc. ... just get values from form ... https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/writing-a-graphql-client-in-vanilla-js-d2a09aee7c6c ... not best (variables should be used, template literals avoided) ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51636430/6124657

Comment: @xadm ty, I'll try tomorrow

Comment: @xadm Hello, I did it approximately according to the guide, but I can't figure out how to write the request correctly in the code, everything works fine on the server: https://pastenow.ru/790699153778849bfa95bc993790a075

Comment: @xadm My attempt - https://pastebin.com/tkttDjXG (Submit.js)
Everything else is the same as in the previous post
If it is more convenient for you, I can show my entire project on Skype or discord, but my English leaves much to be desired

Comment: different query/mutation ... pass form values by `variables` and inside 'input' object ... compare to raw network request bogy from playground

Comment: @xadm I did not understand anything), I meant correctly, did I write a request in the code to register a new user?

Comment: in submit handler ... gather values into `const variables =  { input: { someField: some value ...`, console.log( variables) ... when ready ... pass this to your options with query (your tested mutation), json both into body and use options with `fetch` call making request ... check network details, repeat until similiar to playground